# Unable to import shapefile data (both POLYGON and MULTIPOLYGON) to postgis using GDAL osgeo, ogr

Tags: osgeo

I am trying to import shapefile data (polygons with all of the user fields) to postgis using osgeo. My code fails when shapefile contains both POLYGON and MULTIPOLYGON data.

```
from osgeo import ogr, osr


# Open shapefile
ogr_sf = ogr.Open('shapefiles/tst_2.shp')
shapefile_layer = ogr_sf.GetLayer(0)

# Open database connection
ogr_db = ogr.Open("PG:dbname='geo_development'"
                  "host='postgres' port='5432'"
                  "user='user'"
                  "password='password'")

db_layer = ogr_db.CopyLayer(shapefile_layer, 'tst_table['OVERWRITE=YES'])
```

I've got the next error message:

> Warning 1: Geometry to be inserted is of type Multi Polygon, whereas the layer geometry type is Polygon.
>   Insertion is likely to fail
>   ERROR 1: COPY statement failed.
>   ERROR:  Geometry type (MultiPolygon) does not match column type (Polygon)
>   CONTEXT:  COPY tst_table, line 2, column wkb_geometry: "0106000020E6100000020000000103000000010000000700000083F9A3C6597B5EC0ACADB807A7AE424040B2E29AEC7A5EC0..."

I've tried to walk around defining the postgis table first and then copy data:

```
from osgeo import ogr, osr

ogr_sf = ogr.Open('shapefiles/tst_2.shp')
shapefile_layer = ogr_sf.GetLayer(0)
layer_definition = shapefile_layer.GetLayerDefn()

ogr_db = ogr.Open("PG:dbname='geo_development'"
                  "host='postgres' port='5432'"
                  "user='user'"
                  "password='password'")

# Define spatial reference system
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)

# Create layer
db_layer = ogr_db.CreateLayer('tst_table', srs,
                              ogr.wkbMultiPolygon, ['OVERWRITE=YES'])
for i in range(layer_definition.GetFieldCount()):
    db_layer.CreateField(layer_definition.GetFieldDefn(i))

# Copy features
for feature in shapefile_layer:
    db_layer.CreateFeature(feature)
```

This time the error msg is opposite to the previous one:

> Warning 1: Geometry to be inserted is of type Polygon, whereas the layer geometry type is Multi Polygon.
>   Insertion is likely to fail
>   ERROR 1: COPY statement failed.
>   ERROR:  Geometry type (Polygon) does not match column type (MultiPolygon)
>   CONTEXT:  COPY tst_table, line 1, column wkb_geometry: "0103000020E6100000010000000C000000116AC8BB107B5EC043A499E388B04240D980B833AC7A5EC07653090DC6B04240D8..."

Does anyone know how to overcome this?

Comment: You must cast all geometries into multipolygons. With ogr2ogr you use the -nlt value "multipolygon" or "promote_to_multi". Find out how to do the same with python.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @user30184, your answer was helpful.
I explicitly cast feature's geometry to multipolygon if it's type is a polygon.

Link to the docs: [Force polygon to multipolygon](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/geometry.html#force-polygon-to-multipolygon)

```
from osgeo import ogr, osr


def get_gdal_connection_string():
    return ("PG:dbname='geo_development'"
            "host='postgres' port='5432'"
            "user='user'"
            "password='password'")


def create_layer_from_definition(ogr_db, layer_definition, srid=4326):
    srs = osr.SpatialReference()
    srs.ImportFromEPSG(srid)
    db_layer = ogr_db.CreateLayer('tst_table', srs,
                                  ogr.wkbMultiPolygon,
                                  ['OVERWRITE=YES'])
    for i in range(layer_definition.GetFieldCount()):
        db_layer.CreateField(layer_definition.GetFieldDefn(i))
    return db_layer


def copy_features(src_layer, dest_layer):
    for feature in src_layer:
        geom = feature.GetGeometryRef()
        if geom.GetGeometryType() == ogr.wkbPolygon:
            feature.SetGeometryDirectly(ogr.ForceToMultiPolygon(geom))
        dest_layer.CreateFeature(feature)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create ogr object from shapefile
    ogr_sf = ogr.Open('shapefiles/tst.shp')
    shapefile_layer = ogr_sf.GetLayer(0)
    layer_definition = shapefile_layer.GetLayerDefn()

    # Create ogr object for postgis
    conn_str = get_gdal_connection_string()
    ogr_db = ogr.Open(conn_str)


    db_layer = create_layer_from_definition(
        ogr_db,
        layer_definition)

    copy_features(shapefile_layer, db_layer)
```

This worked for me for about 7.5 times faster than shp2pgsql on a large dataset.